# Regulator of number fields doesn't vanish

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

The regulator of a number field $K$ is usually presented at the beginning of books on algebraic number theory, alongside the class number group, Dirichlet unit theorem...

But the only proof for the fact that $R_K\neq0$ usually involves L-functions and the class number formula.

Is there an "elementary" proof of this? (by that I mean, one that doesn't involve L-functions)

Comment: Isn't the regulator a co-volume of a lattice in $\mathbf R^{r+s-1}$, and as such nonzero?

Comment: @JohannesHuisman that's probably the result I'm looking for, but I'm not sure what the definition of co-volume is, or why for this lattice is nonzero.

Comment: What is your definition of regulator?

Comment: [here](http://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/algebra/ant.pdf) is a definition  (page 59).

Comment: It seems to me that the 2 approaches can be found equally in lassical textbooks :

Comment: It seems to me that the 2 approaches can be found equally in classical textbooks : - the algebraic approach, where the non vanishing of the regulator is essentially equivalent to Dirichlet's theorem on the Z-rank of the units. From this one deduces e.g. the non vanishing of L(chi, 1). This is done in Marcus' book "Number Fields"  - the transcendental approach, where the chain of arguments is reversed , see e.g. Washington's "Introduction to cyclotomic fields.

Comment: Anyway, this shows the intimate relationship between the regulator and the behaviour of complex L-functions at s = 1. This holds also for the p-adic L-functions, but here the non vanishing of the p-adic regulator is Leopoldt's conjecture, up to now proved only for abelian fields.

Comment: @nguyenquangdo Could you point me to a proof? I'm afraid I can't find any. I have Marcus and Lang's books. Thanks!

Comment: In chapter 5 of his book, Marcus determines the structure of the group of units, using the "log" map to do "geometry of numbers". In chapter 6, he exploits these eometric methods to study the distribution of prime ideals, and in thm. 41, after defining the regulator, he gives a formula which implies its non nullity . In chapter 7, he proves the analytic class number formula, which implies the non nullity L(1, chi) (thm. 44).

Comment: I haven't Lang's book at hand, but Washington shows analytically the non vanishing of L(1, chi) in his chapter 4 on the class number formula (corollary 4.4). The non vanishing of the regulator follows from the class number formula (right after thm. 4.9). If one doesn't want to restrict to abelian fields, one can (here and previously) replace the values of the L-functions at 1 by the residue of the zeta function at the simple pole 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dirichlet's unit theorem explicitly states that if $|\cdot |_1, \ldots, |\cdot |_r$ are the real absolute values and $|\cdot |_{r+1},\ldots, |\cdot|_{r+s}$ are the complex ones, then the log map

$$l:\begin{cases}\mathcal{O}_K\to \Bbb R^{r+s} \\ l(\alpha) = (\log |\alpha|_1,\ldots , \log |\alpha|_r, \log|\alpha|_{r+1},\ldots, \log |\alpha|_{r+s})\end{cases}$$

with kernel $\mathcal{O}_K^\times$ is of maximal rank in the trace-$0$ subspace $\left\{\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{r+s} : \sum_i x_i = 0\right\}$.

This means that it is a lattice, which by definition means that $\mathcal{O}_K$ has $r+s-1$ $\Bbb R$-linearly independent vectors within it. But then $R_K$ is defined as the volume of the parallelopiped spanned by a $\Bbb Z$-basis for this lattice, which--having maximal rank--implies that the volume is non-zero just by linear algebra since it is the absolute value of the determinant of the matrix formed by these vectors. Since a determinant is non-zero iff the vectors are $\Bbb R$-linearly dependent, and we know this is not so by Dirichlet, the regular does not vanish.